# SSR for A/B tests in Sveltekit

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte-3, sveltekit

Given 2 scenarios:

1. Making A/B tests for website (with SSR).
2. Making server side rendered UI depends on user's settings.

What would be the correct approach with this tasks with Sveltekit?

`use:` directive that instantiate dynamically loaded components depends on cookie that passed to it?

Answer (score 0):

Good topic!

I think it can be done this way:

```
    <script>
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
    let testName='testname'; // info about test - name of test
    let testVersion='0'; // version - '1','2','3','4'
    let testLengthDays=30; // number of days for testing

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        const d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}


//Test if browser
if (browser) {
    if (getCookie(testName)=="") {
        //Test if cookie exists (2 means that it is A/B test, it can be changed to 3 for A/B/C etc.)
        testVersion=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1).toString()
        setCookie(testName, testVersion, testLengthDays)
    } else {
        testVersion=getCookie(testName)
    }
}

</script>



{#if testVersion==='1'}
Test version 1
{:else}
Test version 2
{/if}
```

But it is not SSR, it is fully client-site

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).